# Set attribute of class with name of class being created

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I am trying to allow multiple models to have a connection to a `Review` model using Generic Relationships provided by `django.contrib.contenttypes`.

Using `django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation` in Django 1.7 you can set a `related_query_name` on the `GenericRelation` to perform reverse queries across the relationship. [The django docs give this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations):

```
class Bookmark(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField()
    tags = GenericRelation(TaggedItem, related_query_name='bookmarks')

>>> # Get all tags belonging to books containing `django` in the url
>>> TaggedItem.objects.filter(bookmarks__url__contains='django')
[<TaggedItem: django>, <TaggedItem: python>]
```

I want to create a decorator that has this built into models, so I dont have to define, for example, `related_query_name='bookmarks'` for the `Bookmark` model. Can this be done with a decorator? What I am thinking of is something like this:

```
# reviews/decorators.py

from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation
from .models import Review

def reviewable(klass):
    # a related attr to the Review model:
    klass.reviews = GenericRelation(Review, related_query_name=klass.__name__) # need to access the name of the class being defined here
    # some other functions are added to a reviewable model here
    return klass
```

Use the decorator like this:

```
# web_store/models.py

from reviews.decorators import related_decorator
from django.db import models

@reviewable
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

@reviewable
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Then I want to be able to query like described in the django docs above:

```
>>> from reviews.models import Review
>>> Review.objects.filter(product__name__contains='widget')
[<Review: Blue Widget>, <Review: Red Widget>]
>>> Review.objects.filter(seller__name__contains='inc')
[<Review: We Sell Stuff, Inc>, <Review: Cool Stuff, Inc>]
```

The key here is that the reverse queries depend on the `related_query_name`. How do I access the name of the class that is being defined in a decorator? Will `klass.__name__` work?

### Edit

When I try what I have described there is an issue:

```
>>> Review.objects.filter(product__name__contains='television')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 92, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 691, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 709, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1331, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1358, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1182, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1120, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1427, in names_to_path
    self.raise_field_error(opts, name)
  File "/Users/atheiman/programming/python/virtualenvs/simple-django/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1433, in raise_field_error
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'product' into field. Choices are: anonymous, comment, comment_approved, content_type, content_type_id, created, id, object_id, score, updated, user, user_id
```

Also, the `GenericRelation` seems to break when I add it with a decorator:

```
>>> product = Product.objects.all()[0]
>>> product.reviews
<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelation>
```

When I add the `reviews` relationship directly in the model definition it creates a `GenericRelatedObjectManager` field, rather than a `GenericRelation` field:

```
>>> product = Product.objects.all()[0]
>>> product.reviews
<django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericRelatedObjectManager object at 0x104b06bd0>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should be able to accomplish what you want with model inheritance and the special case of related_names in child classes, but I have a disclaimer here: this is based on experience using this stuff on relations that are not `GenericRelations`. It seems like it should work in the following way, but I could be wrong:

For example, you could have some base (or a mixin) defined like so:

```
class ReviewBase(models.Model):

    reviews = GenericRelation(Review, related_query_name="%(class)s")
```

This is a guess that comes from doing `related_name="%(class)s"`, which [appears in the docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name)

With that, you should be able to inherit this Base model in any model where you would like reviews to be able as an attribute:

```
class Product(ReivewBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Again, I'm not sure that works. It's based on an assumption that you can extend this type of behavior to `GenericRelations`, but I would give that a shot.

Comment: yea, I tried the same thing thinking that it works with `related_name="%(class)s"`, but it just saved the string as literally `"%(class)s"`. Thanks for validating my idea tho, it seems to me it should work too.